# jQuery : replace specific span text many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a view where the user has many input boxes and each of them contains a numeric value.

I want to display the total of each input in a particular div at a specific place. So here's what I have done so far.

First, the part of the view concerned:

```
<div id="@Model[i].mCardID">
    @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].mListBackstore.Count; j++)
    {
        switch (Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.InventoryItem.mItemState)
        {
            case "Near Mint":
                <div>
                    Near Mint: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.Quantity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item[i].mQuantityToAdd, new { @class = "textNum positive-integer cardPackValue card-" + Model[i].mCardID + "", @id="dataNum-" + Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.BackstoreInventoryID, @card=Model[i].mCardID } )
                </div>
                break;
            case "Almost Near Mint":
                <div>
                    Almost Near Mint: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.Quantity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item[i].mQuantityToAdd, new { @class = "textNum positive-integer cardPackValue", @id="dataNum-" + Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.BackstoreInventoryID } )
                </div>
                break;
            case "Slightly Played":
                <div>
                    Slightly Played: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.Quantity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item[i].mQuantityToAdd, new { @class = "textNum positive-integer cardPackValue", @id="dataNum-" + Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.BackstoreInventoryID } )
                </div>
                break;
            case "Played":
                <div>
                    Played: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.Quantity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item[i].mQuantityToAdd, new { @class = "textNum positive-integer cardPackValue", @id="dataNum-" + Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.BackstoreInventoryID } )
                </div>
                break;
            case "Heavily Played":
                <div>
                    Heavily Played: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.Quantity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item[i].mQuantityToAdd, new { @class = "textNum positive-integer cardPackValue", @id="dataNum-" + Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.BackstoreInventoryID } )
                </div>
                break;
            case "Damaged":
                <div>
                    Damaged: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.Quantity)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item[i].mQuantityToAdd, new { @class = "textNum positive-integer cardPackValue", @id="dataNum-" + Model[i].mListBackstore[j].mBackstoreInventoryItem.BackstoreInventoryID } )
                </div>
                break;
        }
    }
</div>

<p style="font-size: 1.2em">Total: <span class="totals totalCards-@Model[i].mCardID">0</span></p>
```

Yup, a loop in a loop, because the number of items may vary. Next, the javascript fiddle:

```
$('.cardPackValue').on('input', function() {
    var total = 0;

    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    var classNames = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

    var classToParse = classNames[classNames.length - 1];

    if (classToParse != undefined) {
        var spanId = classToParse.split("-")[1];

        $("." + classToParse).each(function (i, n) {
            var valueToAdd = parseInt($(n).val());

            if (!isNaN(valueToAdd)) {
                if(valueToAdd != 0){
                    //alert(valueToAdd);
                    total += valueToAdd;
                }
            }
        });
        if (!isNaN(total)) {
            alert(total);
            //alert(spanId);
            $('span.totalCards-' + spanId).text(total);
        }
    }
});
```

Right now it is working, **but only once**. So if I have three boxes, or if I change the same input more than once, the total is not changed anymore. Can anybody help me achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your event binding is wrong. Instead of this:

```
$('.cardPackValue').on('input', function() {
```

Do this:

```
$('.cardPackValue input').on('change', function() {
```

Cheers

Comment: Well, this had for effect to simply make the whole thing stop to work.

Comment: please make a fiddle, just go to http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/k4JuR/, add your code, then click on 'Update' and put the new link here. You'll have to paste the HTML generated by c#

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the fiddle?  My guess is that we are seeing a problem due to the bifurcation of logic between the server template and the jQuery implementation. Often it is better to send the data over to the client and then have it generate the associated HTML.

Comment: Err... How can I make a fiddle? :( I don't know how to do one.

Comment: But i think you are right. I'll do something mvc oriented instead, which will be simpler.

Comment: @Michael Do you think this is an answer? I guess this should be under comment section

Comment: @FurquanKhan The point about sending the data over instead of trying to split the MVC I think is very salient, and is a good if perhaps vague answer.  If Herve can provide a fiddle as suggested by Edgar Villagas Alvarado (below), I was hoping to make it work using this principle.

Answer (score 0):

Use computed observables from knockout.js, easy with minimal coding